# C# ScriptManager moving script to head

Tags: c#, javascript, scriptmanager

My task is to move

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.axd?path=%2fWebResource.axd%3fd%3dn_OU6GNxoJ7iVZpKadTVAzonufhOkgHe0_PwBbQkpqv4mn07SaiPWytOVRPK4tmy7CPZ29i2_gTLr0gWrHWGXJk9CBQ1%26amp%3bt%3d635195457660000000,%2fScriptResource.axd%3fd%3dc6l0wrIQ7TeYZ-O-mtUW8CgvlN99BvN-QQ1fLBpjSxqLz-HM9gF2bXBD01kOhM9L9jjn0734nLJo9SgBoBCE5mHmwDysclarP5SVZwJeqb5i_tWobz8klgeR8dk3FAvVo9ip0eYrVsuPSaWBw55SCYemqmQZHUWcXD-UWDhvIagq96Sl0%26amp%3bt%3dca758f3,%2fScriptResource.axd%3fd%3dGS6jIZXtw16nxSJ0iN6JRc0fl004uyinq_N_KU5ePPnzAbv6-tL4WNGFNwRfFF4IJAgPXvv-i1IAJfXYzTB51SzGtuSyS1OpvrKwb2Pcnap66jIHGjR3kh8UTs1ekCs5vEi1UoSV3sAn6nHibeJ8jE1jU5P1QCWREOz_CV4jJO3ief_c0%26amp%3bt%3dca758f3,"></script>
```

from **body** to **head** in this form:

```
<scrip type="text/javascript" src="xyz.axd"></script>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you try moving the ScriptManager itself to the head part of your page?

Comment: I did, doesn't work that way, it has to be inside form tags

Comment: I don't think that you can do it. Why would you want to do in anyway? The best place for your scripts is at the botton of the body tag.

Comment: More important: Why do you need it to be in the head?